# Number of subsets in a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an infinite set. Is it possible for a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ to contain only the empty set, $\Omega$, one infinite sequence of elements (i.e. events from the perspective of probability theory), and the complement of that sequence? I.e. the $\sigma$-algebra would be a collection of only four subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: The last sentence of the question is quite unrelated to the rest.

Comment: How is that? As you can probably tell, I am very new to set theory.

Comment: "How is that?" What can I say? When I read these, I jump from one situation (infinite sequence of events) to a different one (four subsets). If you understand the words you wrote, you should see there is a problem.

Comment: I think you mean infinite sequence of points.

Comment: Did: How can an infinite set not have four subsets? For example, take $[0,1]$ as your universal set $\Omega$. It is infinite. Isn't the empty set a subset of $\Omega$? That's one. Isn't the interval $[0,1]$ also a subset of $\Omega$? That's two. Isn't the set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ a subset of $\Omega$? That's three. Isn't the set of all irrationals in that interval the complement of that set? That's four. Please, help me understand what went wrong?

Comment: What are you after: a $\sigma$-algebra containing exactly $4$ sets, or one that contains an $infinite$ (so more than $4$) sequence of distinct events? It cannot happen that both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: drhab: Can't a $\sigma$-algebra contain 4 sets, one of which is infinite? I.e. can't the set of rational numbers be one "set" in a collection of sets that is called the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @drhab Thanks. $ $

Comment: @Guest2942 Please add `@user` to your comment instead of `user` if you want that it is signalled to user `user`.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an answer to at least one of my questions? How about this one: Can't the set of rational numbers be $\underline{\text{one set}}$ in a collection of sets that is called the σ-algebra?

Comment: Yes the set of rational numbers can be an element of a σ-algebra. This is true for every Ω containing it. Was this your main question?

Comment: Yes it can. E.g. take $\Omega=\mathbb Q$. Then by defintion $\mathbb Q$ belongs to any $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, and to double check, is it considered "one" infinite set? Not infinitely many sets?

Comment: It is *one* of the elements belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I see, so it cannot be called "a set belonging to the sigma-algebra"? I need to check this terminology in order to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: The pitfall is the word "belong". If $\mathcal A$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra and $A\in\mathcal A$ then $A$ is an element of $\mathcal A$, but you can also say: $A$ is a set that belongs to $\mathcal A$. In my former comment I said it was an element belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra, and that was unprecize. I should have said: it is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have one more question regarding this. I have seen both $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ (where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra) used, even on the same page of a text. What is the difference between $A$ and $B$ in this case? $A$ is an element of the sigma-algebra, but $B$ is...?

Comment: Then $B$ is a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra. Personally I would denote it as $\mathcal B$. It can be that $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\subset\Omega$ and $A\notin\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ then the collection $\{\varnothing, A,A^c,\Omega\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that has exactly $4$ elements.

If $\Omega$ is an infinite set then at least one of the sets $A$ and $A^c$ will be infinite as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the definition yourself? It's straightforward to check compliments and universal set/empty set. Countable union is straightforward but takes a tiny bit of effort.

Edit, this is interpreting your question as "infinite sequence of elements".

Comment: To me, it seems that according to the definition, this would be a $\sigma$-algebra. I'm asking to be sure.